# postgresql set variable not working with command option

Tags: postgresql, psql

Has anyone a solution for this issue (tested on postgres v12)

I would like to use the psql variable option in conjunction with command like this:

`psql -v env=test -c "SELECT :'env';"`

but this will fail

on the contrary this one won't `echo "SELECT :'env';" |psql -v env=test`

Has anyone an idea about how to solve this or do you think this is a bug ?
Thanks for your insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, as the psql documentation warns about this:

> -c command
>   ...
>
> command must be either a command string that is completely parsable
>              by the server (i.e., it contains no psql-specific features), or a
>              single backslash command.

The expansion of `:'env'` in `-c "SELECT :'env';"` is a psql-specific feature.

I would suggest that the solution is to use [heredoc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) rather than `-c`:

```
$ psql -v env=test <<END_OF_SQL
select :'env';
END_OF_SQL
```

Output:

```
?column? 
----------
 test
(1 row)
```